# Polynomials $p$ of degree $ \le 2$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Find all polynomials $p$ of degree $ \le 2$ which satisfy the given condition:
a) $p(0)=p(1)=p(2)=1$
b) $p(0)=p(1)$

IN each case, find all polynomials $p$ of degree $ \le 2$ which satisfy the given conditions for all real $x$:
a) $p(x)=p(1-x)$
b) $p(3x)=p(x+3)$
 c) $p(2x)=2p(x)$

Any assists would be great. For some reason, I can't quite clearly see throught the problem. They seem like a such an easy questions, but I can't see the solution. Thanks in advance for any input. Also any reference to any website or post to increase my knowledge that is related to the questions I asked would be a plus!

Comment: You are asking several different questions. It would be best to split them up into distinct questions, as each of them have their own approach.

Comment: Write the polynomial $p(x)$ as $ax^2+bx+c$, where $a,b,c$ are unknowns. Then, for each condition, write out the equation(s), expanding as necessary, then solve for the unknowns using standard linear algebra (you get a system of linear equations). Showing your work would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: A polynomial $p$ of degree at most two has the form 
$$ p(x) = a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0 \tag{$*$} $$
for some $a_i \in \mathbb R$. For part (1) plug in the given $x$-values, for example for a) we get 
\begin{align*}
   1 &= p(0) = a_2\cdot 0 + a_1 \cdot 0 + a_0\\
   1 &= p(1) = a_2 \cdot 1 + a_1\cdot 1 + a_0\\
   1 &= p(2) = a_2 \cdot 4 + a_1 \cdot 2 + a_0
\end{align*}
We get a linear system for the $a_i$. Solve it.

For part (2) again write down the given condition for $p$ as in ($*$), for example for a): 
\begin{align*}
 a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 &= p(x)\\ &= p(1-x)\\ &= a_2(1-x)^2 + a_1(1-x) + a_0\\
    &= a_2x^2 + (-2a_2 - a_1)x + a_2+a_1+a_0 \end{align*}
In order for the polynomials to be equal, their coefficients have to be equal, we get
\begin{align*}
  a_2 &= a_2\\
  a_1 &= -2a_2 - a_1\\
  a_0 &= a_0 + a_1 + a_2
\end{align*}
Again a linear system for the unknown coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.